# Added ProGuard and now I can't build a release version

Tags: android

I built a release version of my app and then decided I wanted to use ProGuard.  I added the following to my project.properties file:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

When I try to build a release version, I get the following errors:

```
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp] Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2012-11-28 17:47:37 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

This is clearly referencing the signpost libraries I am using.  I believe I have added the required jars and libraries correctly, but I guess not?

[image]

I added the signpost jars via the "Add External JARs..." button, and added the commons-codec library via the "Add External Class Folder..." button.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

I added a file called proguard-project.txt to the project's root.

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Inside the proguard-project.txt file, I added the following:

```
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class oauth.signpost.** { *; }
```

I am still receiving the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the explanation, but I had the same problem with the guava libraries, having exactly this same warning message. I fixed it by doing this:

```
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
```

Also with AdMob classes. Same thing. So, perhaps you could do the same:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

Since you're succesfully using those classes in your code already.

*Warning*: since I don't know exactly what this does, proceed with caution and possibly try reading about it.

Comment: I have done this and it compiles.  I've noticed via Google search that other people are doing this, too, but I can't find an explanation as to why.  I a bit hesitant to release to Google Play without this understanding.

Comment: I agree, of course. I couldn't find an explanation why it was triggering this warning either. Anyway, I tested my code for the warning-ignored classes and didn't have any issues since then (long time now, app is published in Play --- ~ 1,000 users using it daily), but I don't know if the same assumption can be applied to those you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to tell proguard to not mess with those classes in your proguard.cfg

```
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class oauth.signpost.** { *; }
```

Comment: Do you think ProGuard is obfuscating them and then can't find them?  Or am I possibly missing something that is going to make my app crash?

Comment: This did not fix the problem.  One moment and I will update the OP.